# PHP update query successful but database not updating

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image: screenshot of the code]

I am trying to update a record in my database and SQL query return successful but my database is not changing.

Comment: Please include your code as **text**, not image.

Comment: `$full_name = $_POST['full_name']; .......` so on and so fort

Comment: print the query and execute it manually and confirm whether it is okay or not

Comment: well at least it has pretty colors. gotta give it that

Comment: It is likely your query is successfully executing but no rows are being updated. Check the WHERE parameters.

Comment: **Please dont use extract that way** its just lazy. Also you are not checking that all the fields exist in $_POST so it is likely one or more of your fields in the UPDATE query does not exist.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. I come acroos that my $sql was in wrong order and that causes this all. again thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
representative_id = '$login_session'
```

Is the `representative_id` column in your table a `VARCHAR`, or an `INT`? You're passing a string to MySQL, there. If the column in your DB is stored as an `INT`, try removing the single quotes around `$login_session`.

When posting questions relating to database queries, it helps to also include your table schema.

Comment: Thank You for this information my representative_id is int.

Answer (score 1):

> sql query return successful but my database is not changing

Are you sure that there exists at least one record that matches your filter criteria `WHERE full_name = '$full_name' AND representative_id = '$login_session'`. If no record updating means no any record matching the `WHERE` condition and so no updates occurring.

Comment: or match occurs but no data changed

Comment: @Drew, only scenario that would possible if the value provided for the column in SET is same as current existing value.

Comment: or the scenario that it is not implemented by the db driver

Comment: You mean `UPDATE` is not implemented by DB driver? is it? can you bank on it?

Comment: I can bank on UPDATE implemented. It's return type, no one can bank on at this high level info given by OP

Comment: Ahh!! yes that can be and yes OP has provided very minimal info ... that to only a snippy screen pic.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using PDO (hopefully)

When you're using this Data Objects, when a query is executed it will return TRUE, but it doesn't care if it changed something or not, it will return true when there is not a critical MYSQL Error.

What you want to do is to know IF A ROW AS AFFECTED / CHANGED by that query, in that case instead of using;

```
$PDOObject->query($thequery) == true
```

you should use:

```
$result = $PDOObject->query($thequery);

if($result->rowCount() > 0) ...
```

More info about how to know if a row was affected by a query with PDO

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: this is mostly reliable, wouldn't bank on it